# How to make a method that makes a string null

Tags: c#, methods

I want to make a `method` that gives a `string` (input in method) the value `null`. This is for my database, so that there are no 'open' values.

It needs to be something like this:

```
public string NulValue (string value)
        {
            value = null; //the string-value needs to get the value null here

            return value; //returning the value

        }
```

But this is not giving the string the value null. I think the solution is very easy, but I don't get it to work. I use WPF.

Here is where I want to use the method:

```
string checkcomment = TextBxComment.Text; 

            if (checkcomment == "") 
            {
                NulValue(checkcomment); 
            }
```

Comment: Use `ref`......

Comment: This is for my database - how about `DBNull.Value` ?

Comment: `mystring = null` your all sorted, less code, easy to read, no fuss

Comment: Are you assign the result back to the variable? `myString = NulValue (myString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not make a string anything. While strings are reference types, they are on that is designed to work like Value Type for many purposes. Do not try to learn class semantics with string. You can however set the reference to null, wich works similar to setting a value type to anything in a function.

By default functions use "call by value", wich means a copy of the Primitive Type or Reference variable is made. And you then work with that copy. In order to force a function to use call by reference (in wich the actually variable is re-used and can be modified), the ref and out keywords are used for that.

However teh whole operation makes little sense. As far as you example code shows, you want to set the reference variable to null. At wich point

```
myValue = null;
```

will always be easier to write and read then

```
NullValue(ref myValue);
```

But of course there might be some logic you have not shown us.

Properties can not be used as ref values. So if you use properties, you have to write somewhat more code.:

```
var temp = Instance.MyValue;
NullValue(ref temp);
Instance.MyValue = temp;
```

With a Database, this might be about mapping the .NET Type/Value Null to the Databases Type/value Null. Wich can be very different things.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I added some more code, see below.

Comment: @DutchFatBoys: There is a short version of the if condition you could use to squeeze this in one line. https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator You may also want to upgrade to the "IsNullOrEmpty" functions and it's Whitespace version for your checks. Equals checks on strings are notorious for not working as you expect them.

Comment: @Christopher You mean with "squeeze in one line", that I don't need to use a method? But I want to use this more than once in my programme, so that's why I want a method for this.

Comment: @DutchFatBoys: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref 1. Declare the Argument as ref in the method definition. 2. confirm that you understand that this is a ref when calling the method. This is to avoid being blindsided by sudden "call by reference". Wich is a issue many langauges have/had.